# Can HardHat fork any EVM compatible mainnet?

Tags: hardhat, testing, quorum

At work, we use Consensys QUORUM, and Truffle. We will possibly be moving to hardhat, and thus I was trying to understand if HardHat can fork Quorum as well as Ethereum. I didn't find any articles on it, so asking here.

Kindly help.

Comment: just skip hardhat for foundry already

Comment: does foundry do what i am looking to ?

Comment: Both hardhat and foundry should support EVM compatible networks. Hardhat has been industry standard for the last 2 years, but now Foundry is coming on strong with a blazing fast test engine written in Rust.